# ¿Se puede guardar la información de un formulario en un txt localmente en la web y a la vez enviar estos datos por PHPMailer?

Tags: php, html, post

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de que el codigo en el PHP guarde toda la informacion de un formulario en un txt localmente en la web. Y a la vez envíe dicha información por mail con PHPMailer pero por supuesto no con archivo adjunto.

Comment: Si se puede, recomiendo leas [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar la información en un archivo puedes usar la función [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php).

A la vez, puedes utilizar la información del formulario para armar el cuerpo del mail que enviarás usando PhpMailer.

Se trata de dos operaciones separadas que puedes combinar en un mismo archivo .php